# newly created SSIS package not showing in solution explorer, able to see the .dtsx file in package location

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis

I am not able to see a newly created package in solution explorer, but I can the see the its .dtsx file in project location.

I tried closing/reopening the solution multiple time, used "show all file" option also. Try to add the existing package manually(Process.BillTo) but instead of opening the package, a copy of package is created(Process.BillTo(1)). Visual studio is not allowing me to create a new package with same name(Process.BillTo) also not allowing me see the package in solution explorer.
It is very frustrating and any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Note: Now I am not able to see the (Process.BillTo(1)) package also in solution explorer  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways that a package can be excluded from a project without being deleted from the underlying project folder. For instance, right click on a package and select `Exclude From Project`. The package will disappear from the Solution Explorer, but it you check in the folder, there it is.

I've had it happen where I've tried to delete a package from the solution, but it throws me a message box saying the package could not be deleted, but it has been excluded from the solution.

In your situation, you should be able do this:

1) In Windows Explorer, go into the folder and delete any stray copies of the package

2) In SSDT, right click on the **solution** name (NOT the SSIS Packages folder) and select Add -> Existing Item (NOT Existing Package; that'll just make another copy again) then select the package you need to add back in, then click `Add`.

3) Save your solution.

The package will be back in the solution, and no stray copies will be created in the folder.

As a side note, using the Add->Existing Item dialog box will let you do a multi-select so you can add multiple packages to a new solution all in one shot.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, now I am able to see the project in solution explorer using Add existing item option.

Comment: Don't forget to save the solution before you close it, or the package will be gone when you reopen it. I edited the answer to reflect that step. I'd appreciate it if you could take a second to click the gray check mark on the left to accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Good Morning Eric,
So yesterday I did save all the changes done to BillTo package. But today when I reopen the solution  the package did not show up. So is there any setting that needs to be done in order to load the package automatically.

Comment: @Spanwar after adding the package to the solution, click on **Save All** option in the **File** menu strip

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to "Add" > "Exiting Item" at the *Project* level to have the packages filed in the "SSIS Packages" folder. Adding the existing item at the solution level put them in a "Solution Items" folder at the root of the solution (using Visual Studio 2019).

Solution Explorer:

[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: and click the Save button